# On click dropdown hide other dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown data-filter using it with isotope plugin.

I'm trying to close a dropdown which is open when another list item is clicked and have the arrow twirl down when the dropdown is open.

I would like to know how I can achieve this.

**here is my** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUkku/3/)

```
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';

    }

    $('#nfbt #nfbtv').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fbt nfv');
    });
```

i used the jquery from a tutorial so it is in the html itself it does not work if i move it to its own .js file.

Comment: what is '#nfbtv' ? there is no  such id, so `click()` handler will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi Please have a look to this link. I make it to work for your requirement.  
If you want to change the arrow then add a class which will have down arrow 
css when you  toggling it to down.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aUkku/60/

Comment: This perfect! but when i select the dropdown list it closes and opens up again anyway to avoid it closing the dropdown and opening again.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what you really wanted, but here is my attempt to make the goal

```
function toggle_visibility(e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode != this) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('open').siblings('.hasarrow.open').removeClass('open');
}
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.productfilters').on('click', '.hasarrow', toggle_visibility);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aUkku/4/